# Phantomjs can't load iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a newbie, recently started to use phantomjs with casperjs. I want to get info from an iframe but phantomjs fails to load it.

This is my script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   verbose: true,
   logLevel: "debug",
   waitTimeout: 20000,
   retryTimeout: 100,
   viewportSize: {
     width: 1920,
     height: 1080
   },
   pageSettings: {
       "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1'
   },
   localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true
});

casper.start();

casper.open('http://www.badboysbarber.ru/online');

casper.waitForSelector('.y-main-container', function() {
   this.echo("Selector appeared.");
});

casper.then(function() {
   this.capture('screen.png');
});

casper.run();
```

So, phantom throws an error (although selector is defined correctly):

```
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 20000ms expired, exiting.
```

Could somebody help me please? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` loads a document inside another document. If you want to work with frames and use CasperJS to get data, you will probably need `withFrame()` in `Casper.prototype`.

The following script captures the raw HTML content of the first `iframe` in your main page:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  },
  pageSettings: {
    'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1'
  },
  localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true
});

casper.start('http://www.badboysbarber.ru/online');

casper.withFrame(0, function () {
  this.echo(this.getHTML()); // HTML code of the first iframe
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Sorry, but even if you use withFrame function it fails to load an iframe. Just try to use `this.captureSelector('selector.png', '.y-main-container');` instead of `this.echo(this.getHTML());` inside withFrame function and you will see. This is the whole problem.

Comment: Furthermore you can look at [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/AtbXjGnp7M0) as well.

Comment: If you can get the HTML code, the `iframe` is obviously loaded. You just have an issue with `capture`. I tried `this.capture('screenshot.png');` inside `withFrame` with SlimerJS and I can see the `iframe`, not only when SlimerJS is processing the page, but also on the resulting screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/gWtiY

Comment: Actually, only progress bar icon and css/script links are loaded in this iframe but not a whole HTML code of an iframe. It seems that there is some ajax call for content loading in the iframe also AngularJS is used. As I said before PhantomJS hangs up on the iframe loading and for me it shows white blank box with progress bar icon instead of iframe content. Is this really not a bug?

Comment: I will try SlimerJS. Since you have a correctly loaded page on your screenshot It should work for me too. Thank you for help.

Comment: I have just tried with PhantomJS and I get the same screenshot with a different background. The `iframe` is still visible...