# PhantomJS bug / issue on iframe loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

PhantomJS hangs up on the iframe loading.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   waitTimeout: 5000,
   retryTimeout: 100,
   viewportSize: {
     width: 1920,
     height: 1080
   },
   pageSettings: {
       "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1'
   },
   localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true
});

casper.start();

casper.open('http://www.badboysbarber.ru/online');

casper.then(function() {
   this.page.switchToChildFrame(0);
});

casper.then(function() {
   this.echo('Page url is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
   this.waitForSelector('.y-main-container');
});

casper.run();
```

Simply if I wait for a long time just to capture screen of a whole page whithout any manipulations on the iframe as a result it shows blank white container for this iframe with progress icon at the center of it.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   waitTimeout: 5000,
   retryTimeout: 100,
   viewportSize: {
     width: 1920,
     height: 1080
   },
   pageSettings: {
       "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1'
   },
   localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: true
});

casper.start();

casper.open('http://www.badboysbarber.ru/online');

casper.then(function() {
   this.wait(120000, function() {
      this.echo("Waiting complete.");
   });
});

casper.then(function() {
   this.capture('screen.png');
});

casper.run();
```

So, it's obvious that PhantomJS just can't load iframe source and therefore it is useless to do something further on it cuz iframe loading hangs up.
Is it PhantomJS bug / issue?
How to get data from the iframe on this webpage correctly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Phantomjs can't load iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303851/phantomjs-cant-load-iframe)

Comment: There is no solution to this problem yet. Here is more detailed information about this issue. Furthermore you can look at [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/AtbXjGnp7M0) as well.